# How To Reset Ubuntu Software Center Application - Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: software-center, reset, 13.04

I am new to Ubuntu and have tried using the Ubuntu Software Center.

It shows up but once it opens it doesn't respond.

Can you help me figure out how to reset this application (Ubuntu Software Center)? Thanks!

Comment: Has the system asked to install updates? It could be trying to process updates first hence the delay. Have you left it for a while to see if it becomes responsive?

Comment: I just got Ubuntu yesterday though...

Comment: What often works is removing the applications' hidden configuration files in your home folder- i.e in this case `~/.cache/software-center` and `~/.config/software-center` **and** then reinstalling `software-centre`. The advice for this [related question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/128244/software-center-empty-no-usefulness-from-server-no-username-in-config-file) also centred around these sorts of suggestions for `software-center`.

Comment: Wy you don't try ubuntu 12.10 instead if your are a newbie to ubuntu? 13.04 is still under development.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Your question relates to an alpha or beta release of Ubuntu. Such questions are generally not within Ask Ubuntu's ambit. Please look at [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](http://askubuntu.com/q/18641/25656) for further assistance. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Open a terminal and type:

```
xkill
```

Your cursor will turn into an "X" and click on the window that is frozen. It will force kill it.

After which you should run an update to see if there are any new versions of the software.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I got the update and nothing happened.

Answer (score 2):

Run this command in terminal. It will re-install the software-center and reset your settings.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
```

But for reconfigure a program you can use:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure software-center --force
```

Comment: I tried your answer and when I opened up the software center again it still did not respond!!!

Comment: What happens when you do software-center in terminal? Are you sure there are no apt-get and dpkg processes running?

Comment: It reinstalls it but when I restarted my computer and launched the software center but I still did not respond. Please help!

Comment: Did you tried "software-center" in terminal? In the terminal window you can read what is wrong. But maby try the folowing commands "sudo dpkg-reconfigure software-center --force", "sudo apt-get install -f"

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not sure why anyone new to Ubuntu would be using an unstable development version. There are and will be issues peculiar to 13.04 that the dev team and others are working to resolve, before it's official release date. This might be one of them.

My suggestion would be to wipe 13.04 and install the 12.04LTS version. This will give you the most stable version of Ubuntu, and the version that will be supported for the longest time. It'll also be the best way to learn about Ubuntu & Linux in general. Re-installing is a bit of a drag I know, but for you as a noob it would be well worth the effort. :-)

Comment: Is there a command I can run on the terminal that can reinstall ubuntu as 12.04