# Ubuntu 12.10 Software Center crash

Tags: 12.04, software-center

I looked at many other questions but none of them helped me. It closes immediately after I open it. When I opened it it Terminal I got this...

```
2013-03-15 17:20:07,156 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2013-03-15 17:20:07,160 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2013-03-15 17:20:07,440 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2013-03-15 17:20:07,447 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/importer.py', 51, 'find_module')'
2013-03-15 17:20:07,446 - root - ERROR - Could not find any typelib for LaunchpadIntegration
2013-03-15 17:20:07,518 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - show_available_packages: search_text is '', app is None.
Bus error (core dumped)
```

Comment: do you have internet connectivity? in a terminal window type "ping google.com"  do NOT type the quotes

Comment: I have an Internet connection, I got this when I typed ping google.com

>64 bytes from gg-in-f138.1e100.net (74.125.134.138): icmp_req=2 ttl=44 time=36.5 ms

and it just keeps repeating

Comment: Not sure if this is important or not, But this is a computer that I just finished building and installed Ubuntu on last night.

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/128244/software-center-empty-no-usefulness-from-server-no-username-in-config-file

Answer (score 2):

I realised that I installed 32 bit, I have a 64 bit processor. I Installed 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 and so far it's running perfectly, thank y'all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is likely something wrong with your hardware, most likely either with RAM or the CPU, or possibly the hard drive if the issue occurred while accessing virtual memory. You may want to [read more about bus errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault#Bus_error).

If you have a second CPU that fits in the same socket, you could swap it to test. If you have multiple sticks of RAM, you can pull them all out, and only use one at a time in the first DIMM slot, to test with. If one of them starts giving you a lot more crashes, and you get this same error, but don't with the rest, then that is the bad stick of RAM.

You could also choose the `Memory Test` option at the boot menu, to run some more rigorous tests of the memory. You'll likely see some errors come up during this test, given the `Bus error` means that you likely have bad hardware.

Comment: I haven't installed my gpu yet, could that be the problem?

Comment: If you mean a PCI-express video card, no. You have video, or you wouldn't be running Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try system testing in the applications menu

```
Applications | System Tools | Administration | System Testing
```